# Максимально быстро прочитать большой файл построчно

Tags: файлы, filestream, java

Добрый вечер!
Как быстрее всего прочитать `line by line` большой текстовый файл (много гигабайт).
Хочется читать асинхронно, нагуглился `AsynchronousFileChannel`, но не понятно, можно ли считывать с его помощью построчно..

Java 7 NIO2

Comment: считать, а дальше что с ним нужно делать? Ван нужно со всеми "многогигабайтами" работать? Или все сводится к поиску пары строк?

Comment: Если работа с этой строкой происходит быстро - то нечего заморачиватся, читайте просто по строкам подряд. Реализовывая многопоточность - всё равно упретесь в IO (скорость чтения винта).

Answer (score 3):

Посторочно нельзя, можно только в ByteBuffer. Очевидно, строка может начинаться в одном буфере и продолжаться в другом, и даже занимать несколько буферов, поэтому простого решения как выделять строки в файле и ByteBuffer'ов нет, да еще перекодировать байты в символы надо.

BufferedReader.readLine() все это сделает за вас, почему бы не начать с него? Вы хотите оптимизировать, но оптимизировать надо самое узкое место, иначе никакого эффекта не будет. Вы выявили самое узкое место? Если обработка строк занимает значительное время, то именно ее надо распараллеливать (хотя бы отделить от чтения), а читать можно последовательно. Если обработка быстрая, то сначала научитесь проводить ее прямо на буфере, без создания String'ов, и опять же в отдельном потоке. Читать буфера можно асинхронно, а можно последовательно в отдельном потоке - неочевидно, какой способ быстрее, да и на разных операционках могут быть разные результаты. Последовательное чтение может быть оптимизировано на некоторых операционках (подкачка впрок), так что со своей асинхронностью можете пролететь.